# Individual transitions on Semantic UI cards fail

Tags: javascript, html, transition, fade, semantic-ui

I'm trying to apply transitions as explained in [here](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/transition.html#/examples), but some cards fail to do a second transition/animation. Is it CSS, Semantic UI or me? You can try adding more cards to the test.

Edit:

> As @niba requested, I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xqwz135/) to show what is
>   happening. Look that I named cards from "Card 0" to "Card 7". Run
>   several times and you may see some are missing.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document)
.ready(function() {
  $('.card')
    .transition('fade')
    .transition('fade', function() {
      console.log('finished');
  });
```

```html
<div class="ui cards">
  <div class="green card">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="img/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Header</a>
      <div class="meta">
        <div class="ui small star rating"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="description">Description</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="green card">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Header</a>
      <div class="meta">
        <div class="ui small star rating"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="description">Description</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="green card">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="img/3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Header</a>
      <div class="meta">
        <div class="ui small star rating"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="description">Description</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Create plunker please